# Setting a ViewModel Property Value From XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, properties, mef

I have a view that is declared in XAML (see below).  The associated view-model is created automatically using MEF.  I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<local:MyControl Owner={x:Static local:Owners.ProjectOwner} />
```

The desired net effect is for some view-model property to be set equal to Owners.ProjectOwner.

I can achieve the required result using hacky code-behind but would rather do this through bindings or some similar manner.  Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

**UPDATE**

I resigned myself to writing a behaviour.  But rather than put in all the effort solely for one specific case, I have genericised my solution and I include it below in case anyone's interested.  It's a Blend behaviour (System.Windows.Interactivity.dll) but could just as easily be a conventional attached behaviour.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace BlendBehaviors
{
    public class SetViewModelPropertyBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyName", typeof(string), typeof(SetViewModelPropertyBehavior));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyValue", typeof(object), typeof(SetViewModelPropertyBehavior));

        public SetViewModelPropertyBehavior()
        { }

        public string PropertyName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PropertyNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public object PropertyValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(PropertyValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PropertyValueProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            var ao = AssociatedObject;
            SetViewModel(ao.DataContext);
            ao.DataContextChanged += FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.DataContextChanged -= FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged;
        }

        private void FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetViewModel(e.NewValue);
        }

        private void SetViewModel(object viewModel)
        {
            SetViewModelProperty(viewModel, PropertyName, PropertyValue);
        }

        private static void SetViewModelProperty(object viewModel, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            if (viewModel == null || propertyName == null) {
                return;
            }
            var info = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (info != null && CanAssignValue(propertyValue, info.PropertyType)) {
                info.SetValue(viewModel, propertyValue, null);
            }
        }

        private static bool CanAssignValue(object value, Type targetType)
        {
            if (value == null) {
                return !targetType.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType) != null;
            }
            return targetType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<local:MyControl>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <bb:SetViewModelPropertyBehavior PropertyName="Owner" PropertyValue="{x:Static local:Owners.ProjectOwner}" />
        <bb:SetViewModelPropertyBehavior PropertyName="AnotherProperty" PropertyValue="{StaticResource MyResourceKey}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</local:MyControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target of any WPF binding must be a `DependencyProperty`. The source can be a `DependencyProperty`, a CLR object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or just some object. The target and source can be swapped around by altering the `Binding.Mode` property.

But in this case one of the items in your binding is a statically-resolved property (`Owners.ProjectOwner`). Therefore, it's not a `DependencyProperty`. Therefore, it can only appear as a source. Therefore, what you're binding it to (the target) must be a `DependencyProperty`. Therefore, it cannot be a property on your view model (assuming you've not created `DependencyObject`-based view models, which would be [a mistake](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)).

So, you cannot directly bind a property on your VM to the static property. You could write an attached behavior that does this for you though.

Comment: I understand and agree with eveything you say.  I don't necessarily want to declare a DependencyProperty called "Owner" on MyControl - the sample code was merely illustrative.  I could write an attached behaviour but was hoping, in the first instance, to resolve this without using a strongly-typed reference to the view-model.  Will think about this and come back to you.

Comment: I ended up implementing a Blend behaviour: see my update.  Thanks for the contribution.